# Why does Spyder return its path and not run the code when I press 'Run'?

Tags: python, spyder

Spyder won't execute any type of python code when I press Run.

I'm sure this is some type of path issue but don't know how to fix it.

It won't even run the simplest code like the 2 lines below.

```
new = 8 + 8
new
```

Below are the results I get:

```
runfile('C:/Users/camer/Desktop/Cameron/Random/Sportsbook/model/idk.py', wdir='C:/Users/camer/Desktop/Cameron/Random/Sportsbook/model')
```

Below are the results I want

```
16
```

Answer (score 1):

It should actually be running, it's just you are not `print`ing anything out.

Try:

```
new = 8 + 8 
print(new)
```

You should get:

```
In [1]: runfile('C:/Users/camer/Desktop/Cameron/Random/Sportsbook/model/idk.py', wdir='C:/Users/camer/Desktop/Cameron/Random/Sportsbook/model')
16
```

> Why does Spyder return its path and not run the code when I press
>   'Run'?

It's not returning the path, it's printing out the command it used.
The next lines after that should be the output of your code.